# regex unicode character in vim

Tags: regex, vim, unicode

I'm being an idiot.

Someone cut and pasted some text from microsoft word into my lovely html files.

I now have these unicode characters instead of regular quote symbols, (i.e. quotes appear as <92> in the text)

I want to do a regex replace but I'm having trouble selecting them.

```
:%s/\u92/'/g
:%s/\u5C/'/g
:%s/\x92/'/g
:%s/\x5C/'/g
```

...all fail. My google-fu has failed me.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From `:help regexp` (lightly edited), you need to use some specific syntax to select unicode characters with a regular expression in Vim:

```
\%u match specified multibyte character (eg \%u20ac)
```

That is, to search for the unicode character with hex code 20AC, enter this into your search pattern:

```
\%u20ac
```

The full table of character search patterns includes some additional options:

```
\%d match specified decimal character (eg \%d123)
\%x match specified hex character (eg \%x2a)
\%o match specified octal character (eg \%o040)
\%u match specified multibyte character (eg \%u20ac)
\%U match specified large multibyte character (eg \%U12345678)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me find the right part of the (very, very long) regexp documentation in vim, and I see that many people have upvoted, but I disagree.  Simply pasting in a few lines from the documentation without context makes this answer unhelpful.  Including the three columns on the left is simply confusing, especially without the column headings (which are irrelevant here).  I have no idea what this bit of context is supposed to mean "|/...|".  It doesn't appear in my vim help. The truly useful part of the answer is this:  "(eg \%u20ac)".  Have to look carefully to find it.

Comment: @Mars: You should edit the answer to make it more helpful. Editing is encouraged on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Well, I usually favor minor edits--typos, formatting, obvious errors.  I don't feel it's appropriate to turn an answer into a different answer.  However, in this case the author himself invited me, so OK, I guess.

Comment: For other stupid people like me, the entire command is `/\%u20ac`.

Comment: Also note that Unicode characters (e.g. `U+FFFD`) are different from their respective encoding (e.g. in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). For example, I needed to find [the replacement character �](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) and thus used `/\%uFFFD` to search for it.

Answer (score 3):

This solution might not address the problem as originally stated, but it does address a different but very closely related one and I think it makes a lot of sense to place it here.

I don't know in which version of Vim it was implemented, but I was working on 7.4 when I tried it.

When in Edit mode, the sequence to output unicode characters is: `ctrl-v` `u` `xxxx` where `xxxx` is the code point. For instance outputting the euro sign would be `ctrl-v` `u` `20ac`.

I tried it in Command mode as well and it worked. That is, to replace all instances of "20 euro" in my document with "20 €", I'd do:

```
:%s/20 euro/20 <ctrl-v u 20ac>/gc
```

In the above `<ctrl-v u 20ac>` is not literal, it's the sequence of keys that will output the `€` character.

Answer (score 0):

i too faced the same issue , while in the CSV files we were able to see some space, due to that I was getting the o/p from the program with unicode value.
post using with below unicode cmd in vim ,it got sorted out.

:%s/%xa0//g

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).